# error finding and removing duplicates in java

Tags: java, methods, duplicates

I am trying to remove duplicate names from an input file and print out all the names only once. Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<String> fn = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> ln = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    getNames(fn,ln);

  System.out.println("\n******* All Unique Names*********");
    remove(names);
}
public static int find(String s, ArrayList<String> a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
        if (a.get(i).equals(s))
            return i;        
    return -1;
}
public static int remove(ArrayList<String>n){
    //int found = find(names, n);
         int index = 0;
    while (index < n.size() - 1) {
        if (n.get(index).equals(n.get(index + 1))) {
            n.remove(index + 1);
        } else {
            index++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(n);
    return index;
 }
}
```

How can I print the names without duplicates?

Comment: Doesn't `ArrayList` have a `contains` method?

Answer (score 1):

you can try using HashSet instead of ArrayList.

Save all the names in HashSet and print it once you are done with saving. Which gives you no duplicate names.

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
List<String> src = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> dest = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String s : src) {
        if (!dest.contains(s))
            dest.add(s);
    }

    System.out.println(dest);
```

Comment: @yaya I'm trying to help you here not to do your homework

Comment: library closed. had to move somewhere else.. I'm working on it right now! i keep getting empty brackets printed out

Comment: you have to add data into src List otherwise you get brackets.. Hope you understand..

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to remove duplicates name using Set

```
         ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
         names.add("abc");
         names.add("bcd");
         names.add("abc");
         System.out.println("Names with duplicate : ");
         System.out.println(names);

         Set<String> uniqueNames = new HashSet<String>(names);
         System.out.println("Names without duplicate : ");
         System.out.println(uniqueNames);
```

Pls try this. 
Output :

```
Names with duplicate : 
[abc, bcd, abc]
Names without duplicate : 
[abc, bcd]
```

Comment: Thank you! but i can't use HashSet on my code @KhaiNo

Comment: may I know the reason?